# Adding PayPal Credit to Checkout (United Kingdom)

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal, paypal-express, magento-1.9.2.1

This may be a question for a PayPal forum but if you can help id really appreciate it.

I want to add the PayPal Credit Option to my checkout. I see that the setting shows up when the merchant location is the United States, but not for the United Kingdom. PayPal Credit is available for customers in the UK but I don't see how to add it to Magento.

Comment: what version on 1.9.x are you on? I can't add it in 1.9.2.2 but I seem to recall seeing somewhere that it was available in 1.9.3

Comment: I'm running 1.9.2.1

Comment: That might be your answer then ;-)

Comment: Thanks but that has not worked, I have just upgraded to 1.9.3.2 and there is still no option for it. There is an option if I change the merchant location to United States. Do you know if I change to United States, what effect would that have on my store? Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what effect that would have

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Was not available in the UK

Comment: @jscar Have you got the solution of this? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Narayan no, sorry. As I remember we just disabled accepting paypal credit but I may be wrong - it was a long time ago :)